# Make the shell produced by os.system hidden

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been using the `os.system` command a lot in my latest Python project with some complex Windows *CMD* commands, but I don't like the Windows cmd window that opens when I'm running the `os.system` command. Is there a way to make it hidden and run in the background?

Comment: Note that `os.system` has been superseded by the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, which offers a richer interface for launching process in the background. Per the documentation, _"This module intends to replace several older modules and functions: `os.system`, `os.spawn*`"_

Comment: You may be confusing a terminal window and a shell. Which of the two or both do you want to get rid of?

Comment: Yes, now that I'm rereading it yes I agree with you. I meant the windows CMD window that shows up when using the `os.system` command

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python?rq=1) thread is relevant, although not a clean duplicate. The answer by newtover specifically discusses creation flags in Windows. Ultimately, as Brian says `subprocess` is the way to go.